# Images from assets are not being displayed (404 get)

Tags: angular, image

I have this image `src/assets/images/test.png`
On the main component, I added the following element:

```
<img src="assets/images/test.png"/>
```

The assets folder is declared inside angular.json

```
"options": {
   ...
   "assets": [
      "src/assets"
   ],
   ...
```

When I serve the website, I get the following error on console:

```
GET https://localhost:44370/assets/images/test.png
```

And the image appears broken. When I try to access https://localhost:44370/assets/images/test.png through the browser, I can't see the image either. I have tried putting the image on different paths (inside the components, for example) and I get the same result.

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.4
Node: 12.22.12
OS: win32 x64

Angular:                   Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.4
@schematics/angular          10.0.4
@schematics/update           0.1000.4
rxjs                         6.5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

add this *

```
"options": {
"assets": [
  "src/assets/*"
],
```

You must not be adding the path properly.
Relative path: A path that specifies the location of a file relative to the current directory.
For example: /assets/logo.png

Absolute path: A path that specifies the full location of a file on the file system.
For example: C:/Users/Public/Pictures/image.jpg

Comment: It didn't work. I don't think the problem is with the pathing. I can read json files from assets just fine, I only have trouble with images, regardless of where they are located.

Comment: try run your application with http://localhost:44370, do not use https

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
<img src="/assets/images/test.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in your angular.json under architect >> build section

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
```

then in HTML file you can call this like , Please note to replace the src as per your image path.

```
<img src="assets/images/test.png" alt="">
```